# Responsive Site Not Working

Tags: responsive-design

I recently launched a site I was working on and with a responsive theme, but it displays the desktop version on cellular devices. It works properly on my staging site, but after migration, the live site does not display properly.

Live Site: http://www.sterlinganalytics.com

Stage Site: http://stage.sterlinganalytics.com

I have already cleared the cache and got the same result.

Comment: Need more info in order to diagnose the problem.

Comment: What can I provide you with, @edtheprogrammerguy ?

Comment: Review guidelines for question posting (note specifically the section on Help others reproduce the problem)   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I missed it, I believe you are missing the responsive meta tag on the live site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: You are correct.  I deleted while making edits.  Sorry everyone.